# How I can maintain an active session in Magento (user session)?

Tags: session

Anyone know how I can keep a user session within Magento , I wish that even if the user closes the browser or turn off the computer to access my website your account or session is still open , as I can do it active ? so far I have only lengthened the time Cookie, someone will know a method that can be applied or how this is done ?

Comment: you can edit your old question instead of asking another one

Answer (score 0):

that's the right way to go: Setting the **Cookie Lifetime** to a higher value will keep your customers logged in for this amount of time, as long as the cookie exists in the browser and the lifetime has not expired.

Comment: Thanks but, i wish that even if the user closes the browser or turn off the computer to access my website your account or session is stilled open, i have configured the Cookie Lifetime in 86,400.